# How to convert inorder(LDR) binary tree packed in an array back to binary tree in C+working with files

Tags: c, text-files, binary-tree

Consider I already have a function called `int* binToArrayInOrder(TreeRoot* tr)` which creates a sorted array of tree values (because it's in order).

Is there anyway to construct back the tree from the in order given array, **without** other information such as the same tree representation in pre order array?

How can I write the array to a text file in C, please show me code.

Comment: I think that maybe there is an option to do so but I must mark somehow which cells of the array are leaves. But I'm not sure yet.
And I can do it by changing the data structure of treeNode to have a  boolean flag isLeaf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[1] You can reinsert the array elements into a binary tree again. Depending on the balancing algorithm, the tree may not look exactly like it did when you extracted them into the array, though.

[2] How about this?

```
void print_array (int *array, size_t sz, FILE *f) {
    if (!sz) return;
    fprintf(f, "%d\n", *array);
    print_array(array+1, sz-1, f);
}
```

From your comments, your actual question is how to save a binary tree to disk, and then restore it. This is a data structure serialization problem. For this problem, an in-order walk is probably not what you want. Instead, the serialization should reflect how the data structure is laid out. So, you need a record that describes a binary node:

```
struct binary_node_file_data {
    char data_[MAX_BINARY_NODE_DATA_SIZE];
    int parent_;
};
```

Now, you can perform a pre-order traversal of your binary tree to populate your nodes.

```
struct binary_node_fila_data *bfd = malloc(sizeof(*bfd)*nodeCount);
int count = 0;
populate_binary_node_file(tree, bfd, &count, -1);

void populate_binary_node_file(binary_tree_t *tree,
                               struct binary_node_file_data *bfd,
                               int *count,
                               int parent) {
    if (tree) {
        int me = *count;
        *count += 1;
        export_binary_node_data(tree, &bfd[me], parent);
        populate_binary_node_file(tree->left_subtree, bfd, count, me);
        populate_binary_node_file(tree->right_subtree, bfd, count, me);
    }
}
```

Here, I expect `-1` to be treated like a `NULL` pointer. Then, dump the `bfd` to a file. I'll leave restoring the tree as an exercise. Reflecting on the problem a little more, it doesn't really matter if the traversal is pre-order or in-order (or post-order). The restoration step just needs to be able to allow all the children to find the parent so that they can populate the left and right pointers properly.

Comment: okay but do you see any option to get the same tree without having another array of pre order or post order as an additional input to the algorithm

Comment: @JavaSa: Why do you need the same tree?

Comment: Because consider I want to save the tree as is to a file, I'll convert it to an array of it's values and write it to a file.
Now I want to load it again, so it must be the same

Comment: @JavaSa: You could write the tree to the file, if that is what you really want. But re-building a new tree from the array is just as good in a semantic sense. Saving the tree would make restoring the tree faster, but at the cost of more information saved to disk.

Comment: @JavaSa: Thanks for accepting my answer, +1 on your question.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: no, an inorder list of nodes doesn't allow you to reconstruct the same tree.

For example, the tree

```
  3
 2
1
```

produces the inorder traversal 1 2 3

The tree

```
 2
1 3
```

also produces 1 2 3. Thus, you can't tell which tree was used to produce a given 1 2 3.

For the second question: I haven't used STL file I/O yet, sorry.